# Change value of variables in Vpython

Tags: python, css, animation, vpython

I'm making a simulation about two springs and one mass. I've made it through VPython using some graphics elements. I used the slider function from Vpython to try to change the variables of radius and mass of the ball, but it doesn't work properly. I want that the slider change the value of the mass and the radius of the ball in real time. Can someone help me please :(?

[This is the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BqcB.png)

this is the code:

this is the information of the ball

```
massball=1
mass=massball
radius=2.5
ball=sphere(pos=vector(2,0,0),velocity=vector(0,0,0),radius=radius,mass=massball, color=color.blue)
```

this is the information of the sliders

```
scene2.caption = "Variación de la masa: Variación del radio:"
sl = slider(min=0.3, max=10, value=massball, length=220, bind=acc(), right=15)
sl2 = slider(min=0.3, max=10, value=radius, length=220, bind=acc(), right=15)
```

this is the main loop that affects the position of the ball

```
t=0
dt=0.01
while (t<100):
  rate(500)
  ball.velocity=ball.velocity+acc()*dt
  ball.pos=ball.pos+ball.velocity*dt
  spring_right.axis=ball.pos - wall_right.pos
  spring_left.axis=ball.pos - wall_left.pos
  ball.trail.append(pos=ball.pos)
  t=t+dt
```

[Complete code here](https://pastecode.io/s/mwipe6z3)

Comment: now we can't simply copy all code and run it. Did you run it in console/terminal ? When I run previous version then it shows error in console. `bind=` needs function's name without `()` - `bind=acc` - and when you move silder then it will use `()` to run it `acc()`.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of VPython and Spyder, also I've used the functions described from [VPython7](https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/controls.html)  for make all the program. I really don't know why it show errror in your console :(

Comment: I think  `bind=acc` is not useful. Slider runs `acc()` but it can't get returned value and it can't use it `while` loop which change position.

Comment: as I said - it shows error because you use `()` in `bind=acc()`. `bind` needs only name `bind=acc` and when you move slider then it should use `()` to run this function. At this moment it works as `value = acc()` and `bind=value` - so it assigns some `value`, instead of function and it try to run `value()` but `value` is not function and this raise error.

Comment: BTW: you could add link in question. More people will see it - and maybe more people will help you.

Comment: in your link you also have `bind=B` without `()`

Comment: in link you can also see: if you use `value=` in `slider` then it not use `bind=`

Comment: I didn't test it but sliders may change value in `radius` but it will not change `ball.radius` automatically - when you define `ball = sphere(..., radius=radius)` it only copy value from `radius` to `sphere` but it can't create `reference` and it can't change `shere.radius` when you change `radius`. You would have to remove `value=radius` and assign `bind=function`  and inside `function(s)` do `ball.radius=s.value` to copy value from `slider` to `ball.radius`

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

1. `bind` needs function's name without `()` and when you move slider then it automatically use `()` to run this function with values from slider.
   You had `bind=acc()` which works as `result = acc()` and `bind=result` - so it tried run function `result()` but `result` is not function - and this raised error in console/terminal.
2. `bind` shouldn't run `acc()` because it is useless. This function doesn't change `ball.mass` nor `ball.radius`. It calculate some value and use `return` to send this value but `bind` can't get this value, and it can't use it to change ball parameters. Better is to use `bind=function` with function which changes `ball.radius = slider.value`

---

**By the way:** Function without `()` which is asigned to variable in other function is often called `"callback"` (not only in Python but also in other languages, ie. in JavaScript).

---

This code changes `ball.radius` and `ball.mass` when you move sliders.
At least you can see that ball changes size.

```
from vpython import *

# --- functions ---

def acc():
    dr_right = ball.pos - wall_right.pos
    force_right = -spring_right.constant*(mag(dr_right) - length)*norm(dr_right)
    
    dr_left = ball.pos - wall_left.pos
    force_left = -spring_left.constant*(mag(dr_left) - length)*norm(dr_left)
    
    return (force_right+force_left) / ball.mass

def change_radius(widget):
    print('radius:', widget.value)
    ball.radius = widget.value 

def change_massball(widget):
    print('massball:', widget.value)
    ball.mass = widget.value 

# --- main ---

length = 30.
fric = 0.01
massball = 1
mass = massball
radius = 2.5

scene2 = canvas(title='Masa con dos sistemas', width=400, height=200, center=vector(0,0,0), background=color.white) 

ball = sphere(pos=vector(2,0,0), velocity=vector(0,0,0), radius=radius, mass=massball, color=color.blue)

wall_right = box(pos=vector(length,0,0), size=vector(0.2, 5, 5), color=color.green)
wall_left = box(pos=vector(-length,0,0), size=vector(0.2, 5, 5), color=color.green)

spring_right = helix(pos=wall_right.pos, axis=ball.pos-wall_right.pos, constant=1, coils=10, thickness=0.2, radius=1, color=color.red)
spring_left = helix(pos=wall_left.pos, axis=ball.pos-wall_left.pos, constant=1, coils=10, thickness=0.2, radius=1, color=color.red)

scene2.caption = "Variación de la masa: Variación del radio:"

sl1 = slider(min=0.3, max=10, value=massball, length=220, bind=change_massball, right=15)
sl2 = slider(min=0.3, max=10, value=radius,   length=220, bind=change_radius,   right=15)


ball.trail = curve(color=ball.color)

t = 0
dt = 0.01

while t < 100:
    rate(500)
    ball.velocity = ball.velocity + acc() * dt
    ball.pos = ball.pos + ball.velocity * dt
    spring_right.axis = ball.pos - wall_right.pos
    spring_left.axis = ball.pos - wall_left.pos
    ball.trail.append(pos=ball.pos)
    t = t + dt
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It was really what I needed :D. Also, thanks for all the advices to start in this community, you're a master.